# HTML5: Recurring event on hold - on mobile

Tags: javascript, android, html, touch

I want to make a button that increases a counter while you hold a button.

This is what I want, however it doesn't work on mobile.
http://jsfiddle.net/8FmRd/

```
var timeout, clicker = $('#clicker');
var count = 0;

clicker.mousedown(function(){
    timeout = setInterval(function(){
        clicker.text(count++);
    }, 500);

    return false;
});

$(document).mouseup(function(){
    clearInterval(timeout);
    return false;
});
```

If anyone knows how to make something like this but for touch screen, it would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
var timeout, clicker = $('#clicker');
var count = 0;


document.getElementById("clicker").addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
  timeout = setInterval(function() {
    clicker.text(count++);
  }, 500);
  return false;
});

clicker.mousedown(function() {
  timeout = setInterval(function() {
    clicker.text(count++);
  }, 500);

  return false;
});

$(document).mouseup(function() {
  clearInterval(timeout);
  return false;
});

document.body.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
  clearInterval(timeout);
  return false;
});
```

```css
#clicker {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 20px;
    
    background: orange;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="clicker"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but with this code the counter will count infinitely once you tap the button.

Comment: It now starts when I hold the button, but it doesn't stop counting. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0m4HbfwfKUJQjJ0bDZ5R09NclE?usp=sharing incase you want to see for yourself.

Comment: It already works in fiddle without your edit. The point is that it doesn't work on a touch screen (mobile phone).

Comment: @SJacobs I have updated my answer. It works. For ref see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hh2pthks/)

Comment: It now starts counting when you hold the button but it doesn't stop until you touch anywhere outside the button. All I need is for it to stop when you stop pressing the button. I appreciate the help though!

Comment: @SJacobs No way it works perfectly for me. Have you copied the change that i made to the code ? It works on the devices that i use for testing. You can also see it working in google chrome inspect elements device toolbar which i primarily use for testing.

Comment: This is really really odd. On my Samsung Galaxy S7 it doesn't stop counting untill you touch outside of the button, however it does work using the inspect elements device toolbar.